# (SSAS) Is it possible to group a measure/calculation and use it as a dimension and how can I do this in Visual studios?

Tags: ssas, mdx, calculation, cube, olap-cube

In SSAS I have a cube with 2 measures [Amount of home measurements] and [Distinct count of Patients]. The Sum of [Amount of home measurements] I want to group into:

- 0 Measurements
- 1 Measurements
- 2 Measurements
- 3 or more Measurements.

I already have a dimension in the cube, but I don't know how to link it to the measure [Amount of home measurements]

As result I wanted to have something like this:
[In the columns the dimension [Amount of home measurements], in the rows some other dimension for example date and in the middle the measure [distinct count of patients]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV5Jt.png)

So is it possible to group a measure/calculation and use it as a dimension and how can I do this in Visual studios?